# Permission denied while downloading dataset from Kaggle API

Tags: permission-denied, kaggle

I am using Google cloud services and I want to download kaggle dataset. I have followed the standard ways for authentication but still, I am getting "Permission denied" error

My approach:

I have tried the following method:

(1) Installing kaggle using pip

(2) placing the kaggle.json file in /.kaggle directory

(3) ''' chmod 600 /home/rushirajparmar23000/.kaggle/kaggle.json '''

(4) ''' echo '{"username":"USERNAME","key":"KEY"}' >/root/.kaggle/kaggle.json '''

error : -bash: /root/.kaggle/kaggle.json: Permission denied

(5) kaggle competitions download -c facebook-recruiting-iii-keyword-extraction

error: raise ValueError('Error: Missing %s in configuration.' % item)
ValueError: Error: Missing username in configuration.

Answer (score 2):

When I wanted to download a dataset, I got this error. (I think it's related to your question)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/matin/.local/bin/kaggle", line 5, in <module>
    from kaggle.cli import main
  File "/home/matin/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kaggle/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from kaggle.api.kaggle_api_extended import KaggleApi
  File "/home/matin/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kaggle/api/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from kaggle.api.kaggle_api_extended import KaggleApi
  File "/home/matin/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kaggle/api/kaggle_api_extended.py", line 84, in <module>
    class KaggleApi(KaggleApi):
  File "/home/matin/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kaggle/api/kaggle_api_extended.py", line 102, in KaggleApi
    os.makedirs(config_dir)
  File "/home/matin/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/os.py", line 225, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/kaggle.json'
```

## Solution

```
sudo mkdir /.kaggle
sudo cp kaggle.json /.kaggle
sudo chmod 600 /.kaggle/kaggle.json
sudo chown `whoami`: /.kaggle/kaggle.json

export KAGGLE_CONFIG_DIR='/.kaggle/'
```

## Explanation

In `KaggleApi` source code, it's trying to find a directory from the environment.

```py
    config_dir = os.environ.get('KAGGLE_CONFIG_DIR') or os.path.join(
        expanduser('~'), '.kaggle')
    if not os.path.exists(config_dir):
        os.makedirs(config_dir)
```

So if you add `KAGGLE_CONFIG_DIR` to your environment, it doesn't try to make a directory!
If you got `ValueError: Error: Missing username in configuration.`, you should just change the owner by using `chown` command.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this discussion in the kaggle forum might answer your question:

https://www.kaggle.com/general/51898

It has a script you can run to do what you want.

Comment: Thanks @bgmello for this but I have tried all of this method. They work seamlessly on Google Colab but I'm facing authentication issues on Google Compute Engine. I don't know why!?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

1. removed the .kaggle directory that was created when installing the kaggle API:
   rm -r .kaggle/
2. created a new .kaggle directory in the home directory:
   mkdir .kaggle
3. downloaded the kaggle.json file from my kaggle account:
4. copied the kaggle.json to .kaggle/:
   cp ~/Downloads/kaggle.json .kaggle/
5. chmod 600 .kaggle/kaggle.json